# Server 2012 iSCSI target remains after deletion

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, iscsi

I've got server 2012 as an iSCSI target, and a server 2003 (not R2) as iSCSI initiator. The initiator sometimes hangs and says "reconnecting..." and I think it's because an old target shows up, but when I log it of and log it on again it works again.

Earlier there was target1 and target2 on the 2012 server, then I deleted target2.

Although it target2 isn't visible in the iSCSI target pane after I deleted it, but it seem as it wasn't completely deleted since it still shows up when I create a new vdisk, and also on the 2003 server iSCSI initiator target2 shows up making the initiator confused and hang since target2 was identical to target1 except for the name.

So how can i get rid of this target2 that seems to remain somehow in the configuration? Or do you have any other idea to why the initiator gets stuck on "reconnecting"?

Comment: It's possible you have multiple targets defined for the same target. Disconnecting from the target tab is not enough. Are you removing them from the favorite targets tab as well?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up the Discovery and Favourites tab?

Comment: I cant find any such tab, do you mean the 2003 server or the 2012 server?